# ASP.NET rejecting JWT generated with jsonwebtoken

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, jwt

I have two servers, one is using jsonwebtoken to generate JWTs and the other is running ASP.NET 6. The first server uses the following code (TS)

```js
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken"

const payload = {
    iss: "identity.example.com",
    exp: getTimeNow() + 5 * 60 * 1000,
    sub: account.user_id,
    aud: "store.example.com",
    exc: item.id
}

res.status(200).json({
    code: 200,
    message: "",
        data: {
            jwt: jwt.sign(payload, process.env.JWT_SIGNING_KEY!, { // The key is set, ! is used just to prevent typescript from throwing an error
            algorithm: "HS256"
        })
    }
})
```

The Program.cs file of the ASP.NET server has been configured like this

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = "identity.example.com",
        ValidAudience = "store.example.com",
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("KEY")) // The key is the same used by the TS server
    };
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

However I always get a 401 error when sending a request to the ASP.NET core server. I'm sending the token using the Authorization header: `Authorization: Bearer token_value`.

I'm wondering why this isn't working since JWTs should be universal while the ASP.NET core only accepts JWTs generated by itself.

Comment: Are you sure that the `JWT_SIGNING_KEY` used in the first server is the same as the KEY used in the second server?

Comment: There is no such thing that asp.net server will accept jwts generated only by itself. I would recommend trying to encode jwt i.e by using jwt.io and see if everything is okay.

Comment: Yes @zipsonix I checked both tokens with jwt.io which says that the signature is verified.

Comment: Yes @MRP the keys are the same.

Comment: Have you inspected response headers for additional information why the token has been rejected?

Comment: @Prolog That was a good idea! It turned out ASP.NET is rejecting the token because it claims that it has no expiration: `WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The token has no expiration"` even though the TS server is setting the `exp` field as you can see in the snippet above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Prolog comment I figured out that the issue was that the TS server was setting the `exp` value in milliseconds rather than seconds.