# JWT Token Validation Fails after upgrading to .NET 8 and migrating to Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, jwt, .net-8.0

I've recently updated one of my projects from .NET 7 to .NET 8 with all the relevant packages to their latest verions as well. JWTs are generated with no issue, however, they're not being validated. I'm getting `Www-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token"` in the response headers.

I searched the issue and changed my code accordingly, but the issue is still there. Could you please review the code below and share your thoughts what I'm doing wrong?

I've already seen and experimented using the following pages:

- [Custom token validator not working in .NET 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77515249/custom-token-validator-not-working-in-net-8)
- [JwtSecurityToken in .NET 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77550892/jwtsecuritytoken-in-net-8)
- [ASP.NET rejecting JWT generated with jsonwebtoken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76842174/asp-net-rejecting-jwt-generated-with-jsonwebtoken)
- https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/52075
- https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/17zyzr6/jwt_token_read_errors_when_upgrading_to_net_8/

**ProjectStar.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <!-- ... -->
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
        <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
        <DebugType>full</DebugType>
        <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    </PropertyGroup>
  
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="12.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.AspNetCore" Version="1.8.7" />
        <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.Core" Version="1.8.7" />
        <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.SqlServer" Version="1.8.7" />
        <PackageReference Include="Lib.Net.Http.WebPush" Version="3.2.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices" Version="3.1.32" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="8.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="8.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.1">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" Version="7.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="7.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="8.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <!-- ... -->
</Project>
```

**Auth.Config.cs**

```
using ProjectStar.Data;
using ProjectStar.Data.Models;
using ProjectStar.Misc;
using ProjectStar.Providers.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace ProjectStar.Configs;

public static class Auth
{
    public static void Register(ref IServiceCollection services, ref IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var jwtAppSettingOptions = configuration.GetSection(nameof(JwtIssuerOptions));
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var _signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtAppSettingOptions["EncodingKey"]));

        services.Configure<JwtIssuerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Issuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)];
            options.Audience = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)];
            options.SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(_signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            options.ValidFor = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(jwtAppSettingOptions["ValidForMins"]));
        });

        var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidIssuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)],

            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidAudience = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)],

            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = _signingKey,
            //SignatureValidator = (token, _) => new JsonWebToken(token),
            RequireExpirationTime = false,
            ValidateLifetime = false,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(configureOptions =>
        {
            configureOptions.ClaimsIssuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)];
            //configureOptions.MapInboundClaims = false;
            configureOptions.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
            //configureOptions.UseSecurityTokenValidators = true;

        });

        services.AddAuthorizationBuilder()
            .AddPolicy("RequireAdminRole", policy =>
                              policy.RequireClaim(Constants.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Role,
                              Role.Admin.ToString()))
            .AddPolicy("RequireDataEntryRole", policy =>
                              policy.RequireClaim(Constants.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Role,
                              Role.Admin.ToString(),
                              Role.DataEntry.ToString(),
                              Role.LocalApprover.ToString(),
                              Role.Approver.ToString()));

        // add identity
        var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<User>(o =>
        {
            o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            o.Password.RequiredLength = 5;

            o.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
            o.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            o.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;

            o.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
        });

        IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

        builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(IdentityRole<int>), builder.Services);
        builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ProjectStarDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
    }
}
```

**JwtFactory.cs**

```
using ProjectStar.Misc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProjectStar.Providers.Identity;

public class JwtFactory : IJwtFactory
{
    private readonly JwtIssuerOptions _jwtOptions;
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public JwtFactory(IOptions<JwtIssuerOptions> jwtOptions, IConfiguration config)
    {
        _jwtOptions = jwtOptions.Value;
        _jwtOptions.IssuedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
        ThrowIfInvalidOptions(_jwtOptions);
        _config = config;
    }

    public async Task<JwtToken> GenerateEncodedToken(string userName, string[] roles, ClaimsIdentity identity)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>()
        {
             new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, userName),
             new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, await _jwtOptions.JtiGenerator()),
             new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, _jwtOptions.IssuedAt.ToString()),
             //identity.FindFirst(Constants.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Role),
             identity.FindFirst(Constants.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Id),
             identity.FindFirst(Constants.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Name),
             identity.FindFirst(Constants.JwtClaimIdentifiers.OrganizationId)
        };

        foreach (var role in roles)
            claims.Add(new Claim(Constants.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Role, role));

        var appSettings = _config.GetSection(nameof(JwtIssuerOptions));
        var dateExpires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(appSettings["ValidForDays"]));

        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
        {
            Issuer = _jwtOptions.Issuer,
            Audience = _jwtOptions.Audience,
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
            NotBefore = _jwtOptions.NotBefore,
            Expires = dateExpires,
            SigningCredentials = _jwtOptions.SigningCredentials
        };

        var tokenHandler = new JsonWebTokenHandler();
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

        //var encodedJwt = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

        return new JwtToken { Token = token, Expires = dateExpires };

        // Create the JWT security token and encode it.
        // System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt - Legacy, use Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens
        /*var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: _jwtOptions.Issuer,
            audience: _jwtOptions.Audience,
            claims: claims,
            notBefore: _jwtOptions.NotBefore,
            expires: dateExpires,
            signingCredentials: _jwtOptions.SigningCredentials);

        var encodedJwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);
        return new JwtToken() { Token = encodedJwt, Expires = dateExpires };*/
    }

    public ClaimsIdentity GenerateClaimsIdentity(string userName, int id, string[] roles, string orgId)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>()
        {
            new Claim(Constants.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Id, id.ToString()),
            new Claim(Constants.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Name, userName),
            new Claim(Constants.JwtClaimIdentifiers.OrganizationId, orgId)
        };
        
        foreach (var role in roles)
            claims.Add(new Claim(Constants.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Role, role));

        return new ClaimsIdentity(new GenericIdentity(userName, "Token"), claims);
    }

    private static void ThrowIfInvalidOptions(JwtIssuerOptions options)
    {
        if (options == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));

        if (options.ValidFor <= TimeSpan.Zero)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Must be a non-zero TimeSpan.", nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.ValidFor));
        }

        if (options.SigningCredentials == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.SigningCredentials));
        }

        if (options.JtiGenerator == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.JtiGenerator));
        }
    }
}
```

**Auth.Controller.cs**

```
using ProjectStar.Business.Models;
using ProjectStar.Business.Models.Mail;
using ProjectStar.Business.Services;
using ProjectStar.Misc;
using ProjectStar.Providers.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProjectStar.Controllers;

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IJwtFactory _jwtFactory;
    private readonly IViewRenderService _viewRenderService;
    private readonly IJobService _jobService;
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public AuthController(IJwtFactory jwtFactory, IUserService userService, IJobService jobService, IViewRenderService viewRenderService)
    {
        _jwtFactory = jwtFactory;
        _viewRenderService = viewRenderService;
        _jobService = jobService;
        _userService = userService;
    }


    [HttpPost("login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] CredentialsModel credentials)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);

        try
        {
            var identity = await GetClaimsIdentity(credentials);
            if (identity == null)
                return BadRequest(Errors.AddErrorToModelState("srInvalidCredentials", "Invalid username or password.", ModelState));

            var user = await _userService.ValidateUserLogin(credentials);
            if(user == null)
                return BadRequest(Errors.AddErrorToModelState("srInvalidCredentials", "Invalid username or password.", ModelState));

            //var roles = string.Join(",", user.Roles);
            
            var token = await _jwtFactory.GenerateEncodedToken(credentials.UserName, [.. user.Roles], identity);
            user.AuthToken = token.Token;
            user.ExpiresIn = token.Expires;
   
            return new OkObjectResult(user);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(Errors.AddErrorToModelState("serverError", ex.Message, ModelState));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77641054/2501279). You have at least one problem - `_jwtOptions.IssuedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;` and `new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, _jwtOptions.IssuedAt.ToString())`. According to specs `JwtPayload.iat` should be a number and .NET 8 conforms to the spec. Try `new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString())`

Answer (score -1):

The problem is solved. Thanks to Guru Stron.

As discussed [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/52191), the following specifically fixed the problem for me:

```
new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, EpochTime.GetIntDate(_jwtOptions.IssuedAt)            .ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), ClaimValueTypes.Integer64)
```